# forcing template type to be reference by deduction

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, language-lawyer

Say I have a function `func`:

```
template<typename T>
auto func(T arg){
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << "T is ref: " << std::is_reference<T>::value << '\n';
}
```

Is there a way I can force `T` to be deduced as a reference type without explicitly specifying the template parameters?

Like being able to write something like:

```
auto main() -> int{
    auto x = 5;
    func(std::ref(x));
}
```

but without having to specialize for `std::reference_wrapper`.

`static_cast`ing does not stop the decay of `int&` into `int` for `T`.

Imagine that I **can not** change the function signature.

Comment: `auto func(T&& arg)`?

Comment: @cpplearner I know I could re-write the function. This question is purely out of curiosity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Imagine that I can not change the function signature.

The signature

```
template<typename T>
auto func(T arg) { ... }
```

will never *deduce* a reference because type deduction works on the type of the expression of the arguments, and from [expr]:

> If an expression initially has the type “reference to `T`” (8.3.2, 8.5.3), the type is adjusted to `T` prior to
>   any further analysis.

That said, template deduction only happens if the template parameters are not explicitly provided. So you can explicitly specify `T`:

```
auto main() -> int{
    auto x = 5;
    func<int&>(x); // T = int&
}
```

Otherwise, you could add a middle step in between:

```
template <typename T>
auto func_helper(T&& arg) {
    return func<T>(std::forward<T>(arg));
               ↑↑↑
}
```

Because, in [temp.deduct.call]:

> If P is a forwarding reference and the argument is an
>   lvalue, the type “lvalue reference to A” is used in place of A for type deduction.

So if `func_helper` is called with an lvalue, the template parameter P will be deduced as a reference. In your example:

```
func_helper(x);
```

`T` will be deduced as `int&`, so we explicitly call the same function as we did before: `func<int&>`.

```
func_helper(5);
```

`T` would be deduced as `int`, and we would call `func<int>`, the same as would have happened if we had called `func` directly.

Answer (score 4):

**Note:** this anwer has been invalidated by the late edit stating that OP could not modify the function.

---

Type deduction and reference collapsing are what you need :

```
template<class T>
auto func(T&&) {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << "T is ref: " << std::is_reference<T>::value << '\n';
}

int main() {
    func(5);
    int i = 7;
    func(i);
    int const j = 9;
    func(j);
}
```

Output :

```
T is ref: false
T is ref: true
T is ref: true
```

Comment: shouldn't the first be a r-value reference?

Comment: @BЈовић: it would call `func(int&&)`, so `T` is `int`

Comment: @BЈовић Have a look at [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Deduction_from_a_function_call), I wouldn't be able to explain it better.

Comment: @Quentin Jarod42's comment was right on spot. The function argument type is `int&&`, but T is `int`.

Comment: @BЈовић in the second case, the argument type is `int&`, but `T` is also `int&`. Don't worry, it makes my head hurt too.

Comment: In the second case `T` would be `int&` and `t` would be `int&&&` = `int&`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;


template<typename T>
auto func(T arg)
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << "T if ref: " << std::is_reference<decltype(arg)>::value << "\n";
}

template<class T>
auto func_wrapper(T& arg)
{
    func<T&>(arg);
}

#define func func_wrapper

auto main() -> int
{
    auto x = 5;
    func(x);

    auto& y = x;
    func(y);

    return 0;
}
```

expected output (sic):

```
T if ref: true
T if ref: true
```

Comment: If you change that into `T&&` then your answer is correct.

Comment: the OP specifies deduction into 'reference type' which i took to mean l-value reference. Do you think he means r-value reference?

Comment: Well, I am him. But no, you're right. I actually wanted a way to *specify* when I want to pass a reference. I gave the example of `std::ref`, but I can't adopt `std::reference_wrapper`.

Comment: ah I see. so you need some kind of proxy function that takes a proxy object

Comment: Exactly. But I want to explore the possibility of not having to wrap anything in objects. That's why I bring up forcing template deduction.